# Performance problem with QUERY using BIND variables and OR condition in Oracle 12.2

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c, cbo

I am having a hard time understanding why the Oracle CBO is behaving the way it does when a bind variable is part of a OR condition.

My environment

Oracle 12.2 over Red Hat Linux 7

HINT. I am just providing a simplification of the query where the problem is located

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jun 10 15:40:07 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> @test.sql
SQL> var loanIds varchar2(4000);
SQL> exec :loanIds := '100000018330,100000031448,100000013477,100000023115,100000022550,100000183669,100000247514,100000048198,100000268289';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> SELECT
  2  whs.* ,
  3  count(*) over () AS TOTAL
  4  FROM ALFAMVS.WHS_LOANS whs
  5  WHERE
  6  ( nvl(:loanIds,'XX') = 'XX' or
  7              loanid IN (select regexp_substr(NVL(:loanIds,''),'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  8                                           connect by level <= regexp_count(:loanIds,'[^,]+'))
  9  )
 10  ;

7 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:18.72

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2980809427

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |           |  6729 |  6748K|  2621   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW BUFFER                           |           |  6729 |  6748K|  2621   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   FILTER                                 |           |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | WHS_LOANS |   113K|   110M|  2621   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    FILTER                                |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  5 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING (UNIQUE)|           |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |      FAST DUAL                           |           |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(NVL(:LOANIDS,'XX')='XX' OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "DUAL" "DUAL" WHERE
              SYS_OP_C2C( REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL(:LOANIDS,''),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL))=:B1 CONNECT BY LEVEL<=
              REGEXP_COUNT (:LOANIDS,'[^,]+')))
   4 - filter(SYS_OP_C2C( REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL(:LOANIDS,''),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL))=:B1)
   5 - filter(LEVEL<= REGEXP_COUNT (:LOANIDS,'[^,]+'))


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        288  recursive calls
        630  db block gets
       9913  consistent gets
          1  physical reads
     118724  redo size
      13564  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        608  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
     113003  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          7  rows processed

SQL> set autotrace off
SQL> select count(*) from ALFAMVS.WHS_LOANS ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    113095

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.14
```

**KEY POINTS**

1. I do know that if I change the OR expression by using two selects and UNION ALL works perfectly. The problem is that I have a lot of conditions done in the same way, so UNION ALL is not a solution in my case.
2. The table has statistics up to date calculated with FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO and with ESTIMATE PERCENT 10%.
3. Dynamic SQL is not a solution in my case, because the query is called through a third party software that uses an API Web to convert the result to JSON.
4. I was able to rephrase the regular expression with connect by level in a way that now takes 19 seconds. Before it was taking 40 seconds.
5. The table has only 113K records and no indexes.
6. The query has 20 conditions of this kind, all written in the same way, as the screen in the web app that triggers the query by the API allows the user to use any combination of parameters or none at all.

If I remove the expression `NVL(:loanIds,'XX') = 'XX' OR`, the query takes 0.01 seconds. Why this OR expression with BINDs is giving such headache to the Optimizer ?

**-- UPDATE --**

I want to thank @Alex Poole for his suggestions and share with him that the third alternative ( removing the regular expressions ) has worked as a charm. It would be great to understand why, though. You have my most sincere   gratitude. I used those for a while and I never had this problem. Also, the suggestion to use `regexp_like` was even better than the original one with `regexp_substr` and `connect by level`, but much slower by far than the one where no regular expressions are used at all

Original query

```
7 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:36.29
```

New query

```
7 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.58
```

Once the `EXISTS` disappeared of the internal predicate, the query works as fast as hell.

Thank you all for your comments !

Comment: I assume you have an index on `loanid`

Comment: Point 5 says not... not sure it matters though.

Comment: It *should* matter, without an index you *must* be *happy* with a *nested loop* of `full table scan` -> the actual plan used...

Comment: Sure, but doesn't seem to be anything to do with this issue - without the `or` a full scan is still fast (enough), it seems. Anyway... [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49685896/266304) seems to be the same issue; but haven't found an explanation or way to avoid it happening yet.

Comment: thank you for the comments. Actually the index does not help here, because the original query retrieves data based on dozens of filters. I did some tests and that is not the problem. A full table scan based on a single loan id takes 0.01 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the execution plan the optimiser is, for some reason, re-evaluating the hierarchical query *for every row in your table*, and then using `exists()` to see if that row's ID is in the result. It isn't clear why the `or` is causing that. It might be something to raise with Oracle.

From experimenting I can see three ways to at least partially work around the problem - though I'm sure there are others. The first is to move the CSV expansion to a CTE and then force that to materialize with a hint:

```
WITH loanIds_cte (loanId) as (
  select /*+ materialize */ regexp_substr(:loanIds,'[^,]+', 1, level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count(:loanIds,'[^,]+')
)
SELECT
 whs.* ,
  count(*) over () AS TOTAL
  FROM WHS_LOANS whs
  WHERE
  ( :loanIds is null or
              loanid IN (select loanId from loanIds_cte)
  )
;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3226738189
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                             |  1102 |  9918 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION     |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT               | SYS_TEMP_0FD9FD2A6_198A2E1A |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|                             |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     FAST DUAL                  |                             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   WINDOW BUFFER                |                             |  1102 |  9918 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    FILTER                      |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | WHS_LOANS                   | 11300 |    99K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     VIEW                       |                             |     1 |  2002 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | SYS_TEMP_0FD9FD2A6_198A2E1A |     1 |  2002 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - filter(LEVEL<= REGEXP_COUNT (:LOANIDS,'[^,]+'))
   6 - filter(:LOANIDS IS NULL OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM  (SELECT /*+ CACHE_TEMP_TABLE ("T1") */ "C0" 
              "LOANID" FROM "SYS"."SYS_TEMP_0FD9FD2A6_198A2E1A" "T1") "LOANIDS_CTE" WHERE SYS_OP_C2C("LOANID")=:B1))
   8 - filter(SYS_OP_C2C("LOANID")=:B1)
```

That still does the odd transformation to `exists()`, but at least now that is querying the materialized CTE, so that `connect by` query is only evaluated one.

Or you could compare each `loadId` value with the full string using a regular expression:

```
SELECT
 whs.* ,
  count(*) over () AS TOTAL
  FROM WHS_LOANS whs
  WHERE
  ( :loanIds is null or 
    regexp_like(:loanIds, '(^|,)' || loanId || '(,|$)')
  )
;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1622376598
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |  1102 |  9918 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW BUFFER     |           |  1102 |  9918 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WHS_LOANS |  1102 |  9918 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(:LOANIDS IS NULL OR  REGEXP_LIKE 
              (:LOANIDS,SYS_OP_C2C(U'(^|,)'||"LOANID"||U'(,|$)')))
```

which is slower than the CTE in my testing because regular expression are still expensive and you're doing 113k of them (still, better than 2 x 113k x number-of-elements of them).

Or you can avoid regular expressions and use several separate comparisons:

```
SELECT
 whs.* ,
  count(*) over () AS TOTAL
  FROM WHS_LOANS whs
  WHERE
  ( :loanIds is null or 
    :loanIds like loanId || ',%' or
    :loanIds like '%,' || loanId or
    :loanIds like '%,' || loanId || ',%'
  )
;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1622376598
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |  2096 | 18864 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW BUFFER     |           |  2096 | 18864 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WHS_LOANS |  2096 | 18864 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(:LOANIDS IS NULL OR :LOANIDS LIKE 
              SYS_OP_C2C("LOANID"||U',%') OR :LOANIDS LIKE 
              SYS_OP_C2C(U'%,'||"LOANID") OR :LOANIDS LIKE 
              SYS_OP_C2C(U'%,'||"LOANID"||U',%'))
```

which is fastest of those three options in my limited testing. But there may well be better and faster approaches.

---

Not really relevant, but you seem to be running this as SYS which isn't a good idea, even if the data is in another schema; your `loanId` column appears to be `nvarchar2` (from the SYS_OP_C2C calls), which seems odd for something that could possibly be a number but in any case only seems likely to have ASCII characters; `NVL(:loanIds,'')` doesn't do anything, since null and empty string are the same in Oracle; and `nvl(:loanIds,'XX') = 'XX'` can be done as `:loanIds is not null` which avoid magic values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Alex, and for the time you spent on doing it. That alone is worth of my vote. I am using sys as part of a personal test approach, the final test would have been done with the real user. LoanId is varchar2 because there are strings on that field, even though in my example they are not ( my bad here ). Actually the nvl(:loanIds,'XX') was my idea. I though it was better, knowing that there are no such magic values in the field. I am going to tests your different approaches and let you know. Still, I am amazed why the CBO is doing this EXISTS. I can't understand it

Comment: my most sincere gratitude. You are a master man!!